# TCL command that waits for a string

Tags: networking, switch-statement, tcl

I am working on a script to upgrade firmware on a network switch. There are two commands that need to be ran but they have to wait for the other one to finish. I have used the after command but I am just taking a guess on the timing. Is there a way that when the switch comes back with 'TFTP to Flash Done.' it moves on to the next command?

Here is my command so far

`CLI enable
CLI $deviceLogin
CLI $deviceEnablePwd
CLI copy tftp flash $tftpIP kxz10105.bin bootrom
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
after 120000
CLI copy tftp flash $tftpIP ICX64S08030h.bin primary
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
after 180000
CLI show clock
CLI reload after 00:00:01`

Comment: How are you communicating with the other code right now? (There's several ways to do this; we need to know which to recommend that will fit in with what you've got so far…)

Comment: I am using a management software called Extreme XMC. This is the first time I have used the TCL language. Below is what I have so far

`CLI enable

CLI $deviceLogin
CLI $deviceEnablePwd
CLI copy tftp flash $tftpIP kxz10105.bin bootrom
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
after 120000
CLI copy tftp flash $tftpIP ICX64S08030h.bin primary
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
CLI !
after 180000
CLI show clock
CLI reload after 00:00:01`

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, edit your question (if you can).  Why are you using the after command?

Comment: Sorry. The reason why I am using the after command is to cause a delay before the next command. With the firmware, you can only do one at a time so when it sends the first copy tftp line, it will move down to the next command. Hope that makes sense.